# Extracting text from cache database with Cache Server Pages (CSP)

Tags: html, caching, stream

I am currently experiencing a problem extracting text from a Cache database. My CSP page is written in the following manner:

```
[...]
<csp:search name="MySearch" classname="dbo.Story" where="storyId" predicates=">" select="storyId,storyName,author,notes,text" options="predicates,popup,leaveopen,sortbox" caption="This is the Story Search Box">  
<center>  
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Search" VALUE="Search" ONCLICK="MySearch();">  
</center>  
[...]
```

NOTE: The table that I am querying is the `dbo.Story` or just Story table. The columns in that table are the `storyId`, `storyName`, `author`, `notes`, `text`, etc...

The `storyId`, `storyName`, `author`, and `notes` fields are all displaying correctly, however the values returned in the `text` column all resemble something like this:

```
^dbo.StoryS)dt.common.streams.GlobalCharacterStream ^dbo.StoryS
```

NOTE: A direct reference to the database (a “global reference”) is essentially a multidimensional array reference preceded by the carat character `^`. That character indicates this is a reference to data stored in the database rather than to temporary process private data. Each such database array is called a “global”.

I want to be able to see what's in the stream but instead I'm getting something that looks like a reference. Has anyone dealt with this kind of thing before?